# Quantum Field Theory literature - rigorous and clean

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, education

I'm a physics student that is currently having a lecture on Introduction to Quantum Field Theory. The topics covered are:

- Relativistic quantum mechanics
- Elements of classical field theory
- Quantization of free scalar fields
- Interactive Scalar fields: perturbation theory and Feynman diagrams
- Quantization of Dirac Fields and Spin-1 Fields
- Quantum electrodynamics
- Grinding and renormalization

The lecturer did give literature recommendations (Peskin/Schroeder, Aitchison, /Hey and Maggiore), however I believe that for me it would be useful to use literature that gives a different viewpoint on QFT rather than one that focuses on the same approach as the lecture to achieve a more holistic understanding. As far as I am concerned my lecture focuses on introducing the needed mathematical tools and how to use them, which is also the focus of the exercises.

What I now need as an addition to the course would be:

1. Something that explains the physical motivation and teaches the ideas of QFT, for which I think the book of Griffiths would be nice? (it is recommended in the experimental course and his books are nice to read), but objections can be given.
2. Something with a rigorous approach on why the things we use are the the things we want. Maybe something a bit more in the likes of a mathematical textbook would be nice, as I like clear structure, conciseness (which does not mean short, just concise) and proofs.

Of course a book that would merge both would be great, however I have the feeling that this would be hard to achieve.

I am utterly aware that book recommendations like this have been asked for quite a lot. However they are often quite old, with many books very hard to get nowadays and most of questions focus a lot on the books being introductory and easy to understand or being very complete, which is not quite what I am searching for.